# How to add loading in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a newbie question for jQuery. How to add loading image, when I submit a form?

I want to add image loading, when I submit I added script to alert me if the form is submitted but no loading so no one can see if the submit are submitting..
thanks in advance.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                locationcode: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                },
                locationadd: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                locationcode: {
                    required: "Please Enter Your Location Code",
                    minlength: "Your Location Code Must consist a number"
                },
                locationadd: "Please Enter Your Location Address",
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.post('station-exec.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(alert('Station Information Added'))
                    $('#result').html(window.open('station.php', '_self'))
                });
            }
        });
    });
< /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your code..

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                locationcode: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                },
                locationadd: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                locationcode: {
                    required: "Please Enter Your Location Code",
                    minlength: "Your Location Code Must consist a number"
                },
                locationadd: "Please Enter Your Location Address",
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $("#loadingimage").css("display", "block");
                $.post('station-exec.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function (data) {
                    $("#loadingimage").css("display", "none");
                    $('#result').html(alert('Station Information Added'))
                    $('#result').html(window.open('station.php', '_self'))
                });
            }
        });
    });
< /script>
```

And you just have to make a container div positioned absolute or relative, your choice, with an id="loadingimage".

The code shall make that container to appear just before the ajax request is fired, and to disappear when you choose to display the success(or error) message.